# Dealing with message box asynchronious

Tags: javascript, extjs

There is a function that returns true/false only after a button on messageBox is clicked dealing with extjs messagebox asynchronious.

```
function mayGo(){
var clicked=false;
var may=false;

        Ext.Msg.show({
            title:'del?',
            msg: 'the items will be deleted?',
            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
            fn: function (button){
                    if (button=='yes'){clicked=true;may=true;}
                    if (button=='no'){clicked=true;may=false;}
                }
        });

        newf();
        function wait(){
alert("alert2");
                var t=setTimeout(newf(), 5000);


        }
        function newf(){
            if (!clicked){alert("alert1");wait();}
        }
        return may;}
```

The function continues executing. What is wrong? Why the timeout doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

remove parens from

```
var t=setTimeout(newf(), 5000);
```

so you get:

```
var t=setTimeout(newf, 5000);
```

`newf` was executed, so you where actually setting a timeout on the return value of `newf`. It was equivalent to:

```
var und = newf(); // returns undefined
var t = setTimeout( und , 5000 ); // wont work.
```

Comment: I still have the problem - newf function reaches the end and "may" is returned before the setTimout executes it again